# Why does PHP throw fatal errors and break with HTTP 500 although using try/catch blocks?

Tags: php, error-handling, fatal-error

In my AWS logs I have entries like this:

> [Wed Feb 06 10:12:22.306730 2019] [php7:error] [pid 28445] [client
>   172.31.10.7:55646] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'comet_cache' not found in
>   /var/app/current/project-website-wordpress/wp-content/mu-plugins/comet-cache-ec2-enabler.php:41

Those entries are logged when some certain HTTP 500 request happens.

After checking the code I have found the following (in Line 41 in the file mentioned):

```
try {
   comet_cache::clear();
} catch(Exception $e) {
   // if comet cache is not activated, we want to continue anyway
}
```

This basically makes sense - it seems like the class is not found but the execution should simply go on if this is the case. Why does PHP stop?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are not catching because you are tring to catch an `\Exception`, but what's being thrown it's an `\Error`.

Considering your error message, I would say you are using PHP >= 7 (you should specificy that, error handling has changed **significantly** from version 5 to version 7).

On PHP >= 7, [most fatal errors are reported not by raising an error, but by throwing an `Error` object](http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php).

So your statement could be rewritten like:

```php
try {
    $a = new ClassNotFindable();
}
catch (\Error $e) {
   // do your catching
}
```

Furthermore, both `Error` and `Exception` classes implement the `Throwable` interface, so you could catching that directly:

```php
<?php

try {
    $a = new NotFound();
}
catch (\Throwable $t) {
    echo "caught!\n";

    echo $t->getMessage(), " at ", $t->getFile(), ":", $t->getLine(), "\n";
}
```

You can see it working [here](https://3v4l.org/bebhs).

This is in no way related to AWS, but simply a PHP thing. If you were using PHP < 7 it would still not be caught, but in that case because common errors are not thrown exceptions.

If you were using PHP5, to be able to catch an error as an exception you'd need to set-up a custom error handler. The [example in the manual](http://php.net/manual/es/class.errorexception.php) seems quite appropriate:

> ```php
> function exception_error_handler($severidad, $mensaje, $fichero, $línea) {
>    if (!(error_reporting() & $severidad)) {
>        // Este código de error no está incluido en error_reporting
>        return;
>    }
>    throw new ErrorException($mensaje, 0, $severidad, $fichero, $línea);
> }
> set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");
> ```

Comment: Thanks - this is an important change I seem to only have recognized partly. That means if migrating from PHP 5 to PHP 7 one should check all implementations for places where catch(Exception) should be replaced by catch(Throwable) .

Comment: On PHP5 errors **were not catchable on `try/catch` blocks**, at least not wihout setting a specific error handler. So the behaviour is completely different, and simply replacing `Exception` with `Throwable` will not perform the same function.